# Missing plugins found while loading a transformation on Kettle

Tags: java, maven, pentaho, data-integration

I receive this error whenever I run my extraction from the command line, not in the Spoon UI.

```
Missing plugins found while loading a transformation

Step : MongoDbInput

        at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.trans.JobEntryTrans.getTransMeta(JobEntryTrans.java:1200)
        at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.trans.JobEntryTrans.execute(JobEntryTrans.java:643)
        at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:714)
        at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:856)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleMissingPluginsException:
Missing plugins found while loading a transformation
```

My maven dependencies is as follows.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>rhino</groupId>
      <artifactId>js</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
      <artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
      <artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
      <artifactId>libbase</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.0-752</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
      <artifactId>pentaho-big-data-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.0-751</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
      <artifactId>pentaho-mongodb-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.0-751</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
      <artifactId>metastore</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.0-751</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
      <artifactId>libformula</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>simple-jndi</groupId>
      <artifactId>simple-jndi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: @WorkingHard..tried to change everything to 5.2 but still errored.

Answer (score 3):

before init kettleEnviroment

```
KettleEnviroment.init();
```

you should add this code like

```
StepPluginType.getInstance().getPluginFolders().add(new PluginFolder("your plugins path", false, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

Having the MongoDB plugin as a dependency only works for compilation. When PDI runs it looks for a plugins/ folder under the current directory, and will load all plugins from there. You can override the location by setting the KETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS system property. Either way, you'll want a plugins/ folder and to unzip the MongoDB plugin package (not the JAR) into plugins/. That should put a folder called pentaho-mongodb-plugin under plugins/, and if PDI is pointing at that plugins/ folder, it should load and use the plugin successfully at runtime.

Comment: Aren't there any other way? A web application is running the whole transformation. The web applications dependency is specified by maven. are there anyway to mavenized the transformation?

Answer (score 1):

You must run Kitchen from Kettle installation directory. 

 As written here: 
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kitchen+User+Documentation

> Please make sure that you are positioned in the Kettle directory
>   before running the samples below. If you put these scripts into a
>   batch file or shell script, simply do a change directory to the
>   installation directory

Comment: There's no way to mavenized the whole process?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message after an update from version 7 to 8.3. In my case, it was the step 'Abort' and 'Attend' that caused the error. In version 8 these two steps aren't part of the library "kettle-engine-8.3.0.0-371.jar" anymore, they are now part of the library "pdi-core-plugins-impl-8.3.0.0-371.jar" in a new plugin. I had to add the plugin in the maven-dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.pentaho.di.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdi-core-plugins-impl</artifactId>
  <version>8.3.0.0-371</version>
</dependency>
```

But that was still not everything, I still got the error message. The reason: "To use non-native plugins with an embedded Pentaho Server, you must configure the server to find where the plugins reside" (https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/8.0/Developer_Center/PDI/Embed).
So above the line KettleEnvironment.init() in my java-code, I added this one:

```
System.setProperty("KETTLE_PLUGIN_CLASSES", "org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.abort.AbortMeta,org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.append.AppendMeta");
KettleEnvironment.init();
```

This way worked for me. There's also a suggestion using a plugin-folder (see the link or the other answers) and working with KETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDER instead.

Unfortunately, the error message doesn't mention which plugin is missing. I deleted and added them (in my local Spoon application) until I found exactly the one that was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit spoon.sh and add

```
OPT="$OPT -DKETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS=$BASEDIR/plugins"
```

right after the line where the OPT variable is set.

This is actually the solution from mattyb. Editing spoon.sh will fix the problem for good.

Another solution is to create a symbolic link in your ${KETTLE_HOME}/.kettle directory which points to the plugins folder.