# Pentaho Kettle run the job with Kitchen command - Missing plugins found while loading a transformation

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, etl, kettle

I created a job containing multiple transformations, the first transformation contains MongoDBInput step. When I run the job in the development environment (spoon.sh), the job ends successfully. When I launch the kitchen command from shell, this ends immediately. I read the log where it is written:

```
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleMissingPluginsException: 
Missing plugins found while loading a transformation
Step : MongoDbInput
-   at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.loadXML(TransMeta.java:2840)
-   at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2676)
-   at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2628)
-   at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2605)
-   at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2585)
-   at org.pentaho.di.repository.filerep.KettleFileRepository.loadTransformation(KettleFileRepository.java:1022)
-   at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.trans.JobEntryTrans.getTransMeta(JobEntryTrans.java:1169)
```

Comment: Are you running it from a Kettle directory ?

Comment: in the same machine? When running kitchen cd first into the kitchen.sh directory before launching it.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472517/missing-plugins-found-while-loading-a-transformation-on-kettle