# Using plugins from Java in Pentaho-DI

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am successfully running transformations from Java code.  However, if my transformation uses a custom plugin it does not find it.  In my case I am trying to use the Compare Fields plugin from the marketplace and I am getting the error

Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleMissingPluginsException: 
Missing plugins found while loading a transformation

I added the pentaho-kettle-compare-fields-plugin-1.1.0.jar in my dependencies.  This is the jar that was in the plugins folder.

Is there something else I need to do.

This is version 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your working directory has to be the PDI directory, or you have to set the KETTLE_PLUGINS_BASE_FOLDERS system property, see the post(s) here:

[Missing plugins found while loading a transformation on Kettle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472517/missing-plugins-found-while-loading-a-transformation-on-kettle/28479897#28479897)

Otherwise PDI doesn't know where the external plugins are, even the ones that come with a PDI installation.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping I could just include the plugin jars as dependencies but the suggestion of using KETTLE_PLUGINS_BASE_FOLDERS works for me.